# Unable to Catch Exception and Raise Error in Python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch

Suppose that I have a variable `initial_cash = 'a'`. I want to check if this is convertible to float else I want to raise error for that I've written code below:

```
initial_cash = 'a'
try:
    initial_cash = float(initial_cash)
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError("Initial cash amount should be float or int")
```

I am unable to raise exception instead I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'`. What am I doing wrong due to which the expectation is not caught?

Comment: Your `try/except` block is definitely set up to catch any `TypeError` exceptions in the line of code it surrounds. Unfortunately I don't think it will ever raise that exception. You should look at the exception you *do* get. These are very useful to look at in python. So, did you mean to catch the `ValueError` which is actually raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is in the error message - `ValueError`. you should expect `ValueError` instead of `TypeError`.